# why my hadoop cluster is very slow

Tags: hadoop, dictionary, mapreduce, reduce

I'm running matrix multiplication in  map-reduce in  hadoop 1.0.3 ,the system is containing 16 data-node :master and 15 slave ; all of them is virtual machine in cloud and each have 16GB memory ,150HHD.

this is the mapper :

```
public class OneStepMatrixMultiplication {
 /*******************Mapper class**********************/
//key=Byteupset of line(LongWritable)
//value=Text line

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();

            int m = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("m"));
            int p = Integer.parseInt(conf.get("p"));
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] indicesAndValue = line.split(",");
            Text outputKey = new Text();
            Text outputValue = new Text();
            if (indicesAndValue[0].equals("A")) {
                for (int k = 0; k < p; k++) {
                    outputKey.set(indicesAndValue[1] + "," + k);
                    outputValue.set("A," + indicesAndValue[2] + "," + indicesAndValue[3]);
                    context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                    outputKey.set(i + "," + indicesAndValue[2]);
                    outputValue.set("B," + indicesAndValue[1] + "," + indicesAndValue[3]);
                    context.write(outputKey, outputValue);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

this is the reducer :

```
/*************************Reducer Class*************************************/
    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

         String[] value;
            HashMap<Integer, Float> hashA = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
            HashMap<Integer, Float> hashB = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();
            for (Text val : values) {

        value = val.toString().split(",");
                if (value[0].equals("A")) {
                    hashA.put(Integer.parseInt(value[1]), Float.parseFloat(value[2]));
                } else {
                    hashB.put(Integer.parseInt(value[1]), Float.parseFloat(value[2]));
                }
            }

        double[] myList = new double[10];
        for (Float value1 : hashA.values()) {
            System.out.println("Value of A = " + value1);


        }



        int n = Integer.parseInt(context.getConfiguration().get("n"));
            float result = 0.0f;
            float a_ij;
            float b_jk;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                a_ij = hashA.containsKey(j) ? hashA.get(j) : 0.0f;
                System.out.println(a_ij);
        b_jk = hashB.containsKey(j) ? hashB.get(j) : 0.0f;
                System.out.println(b_jk);
        result += a_ij * b_jk;
            }
            if (result != 0.0f) {
                context.write(null, new Text(key.toString() + "," + Float.toString(result)));
            }
        }
    }
```

and the main is this :-

```
/***********************Driver(main) function***********************************/
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    // A is an m-by-n matrix; B is an n-by-p matrix.
    conf.set("m", "3000");
        conf.set("n", "3000");
        conf.set("p", "3000");


        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "MatrixMatrixMultiplicationOneStep");
        job.setJarByClass(OneStepMatrixMultiplication.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.submit();
    }
}
```

when I start running the program ,the mapper is very slow is nearly pass 1% in 5 minute  or more !!!! 
the conf files  have replication=16 ,maximum heap =6000MB

how to speed up the running ??!! or if this is normal time ??
** note : the input file is nearly 115MB .

[you can take alook in the mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5ayX.png)

Comment: "System.out.println("Value of A = " + value1);" ... this alone could slow the system down. I've seen more than on example of a system where the main cause of slowness were the many trace statements intended to find out why the performance is so bad. Beside, all those hash puts and gets sure will take their toll.

Comment: I'm not familiar with hadoop ... what are you trying to do in the reduce-step? If you are trying to multiply matrices, you will be in very big trouble other than performance. Rounding errors will kill you after the 5th multiplication, if not earlier.  And from a conceptual point of view, did it ever occur to you that AB is not BA for a general choice of the matrices?

Comment: Check how many mappers was running? Add description of input data or little example to be able to run your job.

Comment: @Gyro Gearloose  this run  very slow  in map phase before reach to the reduce. reduce step is for multiply each data in specific row with all data  yes AB is not BA .

Comment: I don't know about hadoop, but string operations are generally expensive. We have to wait for an hadoop expert to arrive. But I really do have doubts that what you are trying to do will have any chance of success. What is the final purpose of your map-reduce?

Comment: Is the sequence of records guaranteed in hadoop? If not, you have no influence on the system if AB or BA is computed.

Comment: in map function :we read the input which saved in input file and give it (key ,value pair ) then in the reducer step the data with the same ker joined as (key ,list[values]) from the data node (salves)  and have operation in in in the reducer function

Comment: the input stored like  A : row:col:value ---> A,0,1,1.0
A,0,2,2.0
....and B:row:cpl:val --->
B,0,1,1.0
B,0,2,2.0

Comment: in matrix multiplication there is influnce if AB or BA is computet :)

Comment: If the values are integers, using float is a sinful waste of performance in their own right, additional to the other problems. Can you assure that the multiplication step in *reduce* will pick up the records in the order you want them? If not, your whole approach is flawed and bound to fail.

Comment: yes of course . each value in A has unique key ,which mean ithe reduce take it first and multipliy it with needed value ,for example :A,0,0,1 this should multiply with all values in the first row in B .the reducer just do take these values and the and multiply them . our (key,value ) that generated in maper assure the that the values will be true

Comment: As I told, I don't know about hadoop, but in general map-reduce, the reduce step has to be associative and commutative. Matrix multiplication is associative, but not commutative. It would help greatly if you could describe what you are trying to do, why would you want to multiply these matrices?

Comment: "each value in A has unique key", yes, but what keeps the system from reversing the order of records so that *reduce* does not get the record intended for "A" as "B" and "B" as "A"?

Comment: I'm research assistant and know I'm testing the hadoop environment in many side and application such as sorting ,search and matrix multiplication which used in graphics in  with large data file  ,the main gool is speed up these operation

Comment: each key of A is connected to list of values in B ,the reducer check that it read the A value then multiply it with the related values in B

Comment: "the main gool is speed up these operation" -- I see, so in this case it doesn't matter if the result is plain nonsense as long as it is good enough for performance statistics ;-) OK, so what I have spotted: string operations are a performance killer, anywhere, and nearly anyhow. There are other performance killers, but they have to do with matrix multiplication which is not your ultimate research goal.

Comment: this connection between A and B as (key,value ) is the main base of map -reduce function

Comment: Ok,thank you @Gyro Gearloose :)